# Could typescript be able to understand whether an array is non-empty and infer types of some array methods accordingly?

Tags: arrays, typescript, lodash

I recently updated typescript and lodash, and now the compiler understands that e.g. methods like `_.last()` will return a value if the array is non-empty and undefined if it's empty. This is expected behavior as such, especially if we don't know if the array is empty or not.

However, in cases such as calling `_.last([1,2,3])`, we *just know* that the array is non-empty and this will always return a number. Moreover, I have several places in the code where I have checked for non-emptiness, and act accordingly, like:

```
if (!_.isEmpty(array)) {
  return _.last(array);
}
```

... where by just looking at that code, we know the statement will return an element with the type of an element in that array. But the return type is `T | undefined` nevertheless.

I know that I can just cast the value in cases like this. But I'd rather avoid casting things.

So my question is: could it be possible for typescript to understand situations like these?

Answer (score 2):

We can create a system where `isEmpty` adds information to the type of the array. This can be a type we can call `HasElements<T>` where `T` can `true` or `false`. If the type is still untested, it should have both possibilities in it's type (`T[] & (HasElements<true> | HasElements<false>)`). This has to be added manually to the type unfortunately.

```
import _ from 'lodash'

declare module 'lodash' {
    type HasElements<T extends boolean> = T extends boolean ? { // distributive conditional, makes HasElements<boolean> == HasElements<true> | HasElements<false>
        "gurad-traits"?: {
            hasElements?: T
        }
    }: never
    interface LoDashStatic {
        isEmpty<T extends HasElements<boolean>>(value?: T): value is T & HasElements<false>;
        last<T> (array: List<T> & HasElements<true>): T;
        last<T> (array: (List<T> & HasElements<false> )| null | undefined): undefined;
}
}

function test<T>(array: T[] & _.HasElements<boolean>, defaultValue: T): T {
    if (!_.isEmpty(array)) {
        return _.last(array);
    }else {
        let u: T = _.last(array); /// err, returns undefined
        return defaultValue;
    }
}

test([1,2,3], 1); //HasElements does not influence the assignability of arrays
```

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for sharing this!

Comment: @Timzai not sure if it's useful, we can do a lot of acrobatics in the type system doesn't mean we always should. You decide if it's worth the trouble :). Let me know if you end up using any of it and have any other issues, it's a very interesting topic :)

Comment: I probably will not end up using this, as I would need to add the extended type to a lot of places and it is a thing the developer of this product would need to remember, so not nice. Therefore, I would wish this would come natively either from the typescript language or a linter. But your answer widened my mind, so it's useful in that sense :)